# Python in java, is it possible

Tags: java, python

I have a class that is written in Java.
Can it be used in Python so i dont have to rewrite it?

Comment: Wait, wat? You'll have to clarify... extensively. Run Python on a JVM (in that case, Jython is the answer)? Generate Java code from Python? [enter another interpretation here]?

Comment: I have a class that is written in Java. Can it be used in Python so i dont have to rewrite it?

Comment: Thanks. So Jython is indeed the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to do exactly what I need.

Comment: How big is your class? Rewriting could probably be the fastest solution (think of how expressive Python is compared to Java).

Comment: About 1800 lines. Its not huge, but it is a little large. Its just making sure I get all the logic correct. The class is tried and proven. But it is definitely an option. As Goran suggests, I will also require a JRE to run my python script which seems like a unnecessary dependency issue

Comment: Ummm ... if the class is 1800 lines long, may be it **needs** to be rewritten.

Comment: By my standards, 1800 lines is huge, and probably inexcusably so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JYthon is a python implementation in java , you should check it out

www.jython.org

Comment: Yes, this is interesting. I will have to investigate this

Answer (score 3):

See this: http://jpype.sourceforge.net/

Might not be worth the trouble, though..

Comment: I have a class that is already written in Java. I need to use python for this particular project. It would be a pain to have to rewrite it in Python. This is also a very interesting response. I need to investigate this. Seems like there might be quite a bit of overhead associated with it though

Comment: What i meant by 'not be worth the trouble' is that rewriting the class just might be the simplest solution. Keep in mind the way you python code should be deployed. If you use your Java class, it requires you to install and deploy at least JRE

Comment: True, that is a good point. It would be rather time consuming to rewrite it though and debug it. This is definitely interesting though. i am going to explore this and Jython before I begin anything